# thread processing in while loop in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            words.setText(cursor.getString(1) + " :  " + cursor.getString(2));
            image.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(words.getMeasuredHeight(),words.getMeasuredHeight()));

            ll.addView(words);
            ll.addView(image);
            wm.addView(ll, parameters);

            final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animator.setRepeatCount(0); // Times of repeat
            animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(4000); //Fast and Furious
            // animator.setStartDelay(5000);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    final float width = words.getWidth();
                    final float translationX = width * progress;
                    words.setTranslationX(translationX);
                    words.setTranslationX(width - translationX); //Right to Left
                }
            });

            animator.start();
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ll.removeView(words);
                            ll.removeView(image);
                            wm.removeView(ll);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is my code. I have am issue in threads (i think so). As you see. cursor gets all data in my database. After that, it get each one through while loop.
When loop started,  `animator.start()` run in 7s. But `while loop` finished earlier. So in next loop, it can't `addView()` because it doesn't remove `removeView`. It look like this picture: [processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HI1G.png).So, the `while loop` need finished threads before running new loop.
I'm a newer in Java and i dont understand about threads much. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You should certainly add both the listeners before starting your thread.

Comment: And you should probably not reinvent ListView/RecyclerView

Comment: I tried adding `notify()` in both listener after adding `wating()` at bottom While but no working. :(